# Spring boot and JCA providers

Tags: spring-boot, bouncycastle, jce

I have a Spring boot(1.4.2.RELEASE) project with bouncycastle as a dependency in the pom.xml as in the following:

```
pom.xml
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.54</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.54</version>
</dependency>
...
```

However, when I attempt to specify "BC" as the provider for a JCA operation in my code, such as:

`Signature aSig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA","BC");`

I get the standard no such provider exception:

`java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC`

despite having the entry

`security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

in my jre's java.security file.

With this dependency in my pom file, the built jar has the bouncy castle jars in the BOOT-INF/lib folder:

```
3277268 Tue Dec 29 12:46:28 EST 2015 BOOT-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar
673715 Tue Dec 29 12:46:02 EST 2015 BOOT-INF/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.54.jar
```

I can access the classes within them with no issue but JCA can't find the provider.

So, does JCA *require* the provider jars to be in jre/lib/ext?

...or am I simply missing something?

EDIT:

However, this:

`Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA",new BouncyCastleProvider());`

works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the Bouncycastle provider before using it. See http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation

**Installing the Provider Dynamically**

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

**Installing the Provider Statically**

Add the provider as the last  entry in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`

```
security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Add the Bouncy Castle provider jar to the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`

Comment: I do the static installation...see my original post.

Comment: Then, you need to add the jars into `jre/lib/ext`, also do not use positión 1 because 'bouncycastle' can have dependencies. See this link of Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html which references bouncycastle. in these  other links also indicate that is needed to include the jars into JVM `lib/ext` http://tomee.apache.org/bouncy-castle.html https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch09s19s04s04.html

Comment: Thanks for your responses...I appreciate them.  As to your comment though, why does: signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA",new BouncyCastleProvider()); work but signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA","BC"); fail when the jars are *not* in the jre/lib/ext folder?

Comment: I guess it is a classloader issue. Static initialization when  the jars are not in `jre/lib/ext` fails because the provider instantiation is done by JVM, and the classpath of your application is not visible globally. Probably you will found the error in some log. `signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA","BC")` fails consencuently because provider is not initialized. `new BouncyCastleProvider()` instantiates the provider dinamically using the application classpath, so bouncycastle jars are visible. `signature.getInstance()` will use the recently created provider and works.

Comment: What would be the way to do this in JDK11 since there is not lib/ext folder anymore?